# Is this query injection proof?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

I am using PDO to talk to my database, and I wonder if casting a type like this

```
$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id=".(int)$id);
```

is sufficient to prevent sql injection? In this case $id is always an integer.

I also wonder what would be a good way to prevent an injection in this kind of statement if the variable was a string.

Comment: The best way is to use parameterized queries.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but how do I do it in this case?

Comment: The best way is to use parameterized stored procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Casting to int prevents all the nasty SQL injection possibilities.

If the variable were a string, you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to pass it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using PDO, a better approach will be to use:

- [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

This is much better:

```
$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id = ?");
$dbh->bindParam(1, (int) $id);
// more code.....
```

Comment: So if I use them, I do not need to worry about sanitizing anything?

Comment: @Michael: Sanitalizing is still always a good idea but prepared statements are far more better in order to prevent sql injection.

Comment: I heard that PDO takes care of it by default. Isn't that so?

Comment: @Michael: unless you use prepared statements out of the PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape table and field names in query:

```
$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `recipes` WHERE `id=`'".(int)$id."'");
```

Comment: two mistakes in attempt to improve... :-O

Comment: It's not a *must* unless it's a keyword, but yes, it is good practice to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically cast `$id` to an integer, it is safe. For a string (or any other data type) you need to escape it before executing the query; have a look at [`PDO::quote`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bind to a integer is enough to prevent SQL  Injection if the parameter is expected as a integer.

You can also use an [Automatic SQL Injection Tool](http://sec4app.com/WebCruiser-Web-Vulnerability-Scanner.htm) to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Careful though, in PHP `(int)` will convert NULL to 0.

Therefore, If you had an significant association with the ID of 0 in your application, this could trigger that value unintentionally.

Comment: `(int) will convert NULL to 0` - `$id = str_replace("\0", "", $id)` should solve that